# When do we really need to use hibernate for our Java code?

Tags: java, database

As a beginner to Java-database projects, how does one decide when one should use Hibernate in Java code instead of simple jdbc?

Comment: @Ravi - thanks for the link. I was wondering if it is good to learn hibernate is one is weak in databases and java. I mean, i am not a pro.

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for stackoverflow since every answer is equally valid. Please read the stackoverflow FAQ to see more on this. Voting to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use hibernate if 1 to 4 are satisfied

1. If you are designing the database schema and your domain objects afresh.
2. You envision that your domain objects and your schema will be in sync, for example an automobile vendor application where your vehicle objects are likely to be close to your table structures. Just an example.
3. You really want to use an ORM and tie your objects closely to schema.
4. Want to use a ORM framework to handle connections etc.

Else

I would recommend ibatis. This is still an ORM framework but leaves flexibility in handling schema and domain objects separatley. It offers more flexibility in handling queries etc.

Spring jdbc also has good features offering flexibility. But i feel it still not near to an ORM. But spring does offer templates to handle orms like hibernate and ibatis.

Comment: Hibernate's been pretty excellent for me for queries -- even doing major database/application migration & re-engineering work, I could do almost everything with Criteria & had to go to HSQL only twice.

Comment: Hibernate's also effectively the industry standard -- and more heavily tested/ proven/ documented/ wider skillbase. Not perfect, but mostly pretty good. If you don't have a reason to make variant architectural choices, don't.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, if your application needs to store some data, you will probably want to use an ORM (e.g. you built some business app for your company and you need to track users and accounts).  If your application *is* your data, then you will probably want to use JDBC (e.g. you built a data warehouse for your company).

as an additional note, it's perfectly reasonable for an application to use *both* ORM and JDBC.  if, for instance, you were building a webapp which was allowing users to access your data warehouse, you might manage the user/account info using ORM but use JDBC to interact with the data warehouse.

Comment: "your application is your data" - what does this mean ?

Comment: it means that the whole point of your application is managing data.

Comment: Good answer, thanks jtahlborn! **I completely get what you mean.**